# Markov chain explanation

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process

I'm reading Norris' book on Markov chains and am unsure about how the relation $P^{n+1} = P^n P$ was used to obtain the last equation in the following example.

[Example 1.1.4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkMx5.png)

Sorry it's probably an elementary question but I'm new to Markov chains so if someone could explain it I'd really appreciate it, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$p_{11}^{(n+1)}$ is the $(1,1)$ entry of the matrix $P^{n+1}$. If you think about how matrix multiplication works, you can see that this is equal to the dot product of the first row of $P^n$ (which has entries $p^{(n)}_{11}$ and $p^{(n)}_{12}$) with the first column of $P$ (which has entries $1-\alpha$ and $\beta$).

Comment: ohhh of course! thank you!!